# Optimizing with Many Langrangians

Tags: optimization

I'm working on a problem where I've got to minimize the following:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(a+c\sqrt{(y_i^2+1)}+dy_i-v_i)^2$

with the following constraints:

$0\leq c \leq 4e$

$|d| \leq c \mbox{ and } |d| \leq 4e-c$

$a \leq c \leq f$

Where $e$ and $f$ are just two constants.

Perhaps I'm doing something quite stupid, but doesn't this yield 6^2 complementary conditions to check?